# I would like to validate an uploaded image for a custom post type before upload

Tags: wordpress, upload

I would like to check an image before uploading it to the server.
I need to check if it has a minimum width and height, 300dpi and only jpg.

I'm using the next function to invoke the upload process, except it invokes on every upload not for a certain post type.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','tc_handle_upload_prefilter');

function mf_handle_upload_prefilter($file)
{
  // do checks and return error if fails

  return $file;
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Can I maybe at an extra value to the $file parameter which I can use?
Or is there another way to do this?

ps. I has to be before the upload itself!

Comment: Research here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_handle_upload_prefilter

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo found what I was looking for! Solved it with:

`get_post_type($_REQUEST['post_id']) == 'post'`

Comment: If you publish the solution as an Answer, the better ;)

Answer (score 3):

The solution:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','tc_handle_upload_prefilter');

function mf_handle_upload_prefilter($file)
{
  if(get_post_type($_REQUEST['post_id']) == 'post_type')
  {
     // do checks
  }

  return $file;
}
```